# Postgresql: levenshtein distance in a row column with comma-separated values

Tags: arrays, postgresql, levenshtein-distance

I have a table with the following content :

`ID | Name | Alias`

`1 | William | Will,Willo,Wolli`

I would like to return the row ID if the levenshtein distance (or metaphone, it does not matter) of a user-supplied string is lower than a defined threshold for the user name or any of the known aliases.

I know that a possible solution is to use an additional table linking user IDs with user aliases, although I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is string split/explode. It could be done like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN
(SELECT u.id,unnest(string_to_array(u.alias, ',')) AS ALIAS FROM users AS u) AS q
ON u.id=q.id
WHERE levenshtein(u.name,'Jill')<3
OR levenshtein(q.ALIAS,'Jill')<3;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/494e6/5

Answer (score 2):

As usual, there is more than one solution:

```
select  u.id
from    users u
where   3 >
any
(
    select  levenshtein ( 'Willey'::text, a )
    from    regexp_split_to_table
        (
            concat_ws ( ',' , u.name::text , u.alias::text )
        ,   ','
        ) as a
)
```